# Sum of factors from consecutive sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$24$ can be written as $2\times 3\times 4$, $2\times 2\times 6$, $1\times 4\times 6$ or $1\times 3\times 8$.

The sums of those triples are $2+3+4=9$, $2+2+6=10$, $1+4+6=11$, $1+3+8=12$.

That is a consecutive string $9$, $10$, $11$, $12$ of length $4$.

Are there other numbers, instead of $24$, that factor into triples, where the triples' sums form a consecutive string much longer than that - as long as you like?

EDIT : The number 1441440 is made from triples that sum to any number from 343 to 377.

Comment: I assume you don't want two 1's as in 1*1*24. It would help if you spell out the assumptions ("rules") on the factorizations, and also whether the products used have to include *all* of the products which fit the rules, or on the other hand might use only some of them.

Comment: 1+1+24 isn't close to another one, so it doesn't matter.  I also didn't include 1*2*12.  On the other hand, I did include 2*2*6, so repetition is allowed,

Comment: Is a valid, and more rigorous way of stating this statement follows: "Given an $n$, $a$ and $b$, is there an $m$, such that there for each $k$ in $a, a+1, \dots a+n$, there is an unordered $b$-tuple of positive integers, which multiply to $m$, and sum to $k$" ?

Comment: I intended $b=3$, although you have a good answer for other $b$.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to let the factorizations be large (but all the same length), then powers of 2 can produce very long strings of consecutive integers through a 22/14 interchange. For instance,

$$64 = 2\times2\times2\times2\times2\times2 \to 12$$
$$64 = 1\times2\times2\times2\times2\times4 \to 13$$
$$64 = 1\times1\times2\times2\times4\times4 \to 14$$
$$64 = 1\times1\times1\times4\times4\times4 \to 15$$

... and by taking larger powers of 2, I can clearly make arbitrarily long strings. In fact, the above can be extended a few more times by interchanging 44/28, which lets us increment by 2:

$$64 = 1\times1\times2\times2\times2\times8 \to 16$$
$$64 = 1\times1\times1\times2\times4\times8 \to 17$$

If this feels "cheaty" with all the extra factors of 1, you can just build chains like

$$1024 = (2,2,4,4,4,4) \to 20$$
$$1024 = (1,4,4,4,4,4) \to 21$$
$$1024 = (2,2,4,4,2,8) \to 22$$
$$1024 = (1,4,4,4,2,8) \to 23$$
$$1024 = (2,2,2,8,2,8) \to 24$$
$$1024 = (1,4,2,8,2,8) \to 25$$

This just uses the two "exchanges" above, and only ever has a single "1". (And clearly generalizes to build very long strings).